# Problemas al buscar por código en una aplicación web con primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, netbeans-8.2

El problema que me encuentro es que al momento de buscar el código para modificar en un datatable al seleccionar cualquier fila los campos aparecen en una ventana de dialogo pero aparecen vacíos alguien que me ayude o explique como hallar una solución soy nuevo haciendo proyectos web

La clase Mercado

```
public class Mercado {

private int codigo;
private String nombre;
private String direccion;

 @Override
public String toString() {
return String.format("%s[codigo=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(),  
getCodigo());
}

 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.codigo;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Mercado other = (Mercado) obj;
    if (this.codigo != other.codigo) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public Mercado() {
}

public Mercado(int codigo, String nombre, String direccion) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
}
```

La capa de negocios de Funciones para el obtener

```
public class FMercado {
public static Mercado obtener(int  codigo){
   Mercado mercado=null;
   Conexion con=new Conexion();
   String sql="SELECT codigo, nombre, direccion FROM 
  mercado_comprobantes.mercado where codigo=?";


    List<Parametro> lst= new ArrayList<>();
    lst.add(new Parametro(1,codigo));
    ResultSet rst= con.ejecutaQuery(sql, lst);
    try {
        while(rst.next()){
        mercado=new Mercado();
        mercado.setCodigo(rst.getInt("codigo"));
        mercado.setNombre(rst.getString("nombre"));
        mercado.setDireccion(rst.getString("direccion"));
    }

        con.desconectar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return mercado;
}
```

El controlador MercadoBean

```
@ManagedBean

@ViewScoped
public class MercadoBean **texto en negrita**{
private Mercado mercado = new Mercado();
 public void obtener() throws Exception{
    try{
        FMercado fmercado = new FMercado(); 

      if(FMercado.obtener(0)==null){
          FMercado.obtener(mercado.getCodigo());
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Aviso","Exito"));

        }else{
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,"Aviso","Error"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Lo que veo raro es que MercadoBean uses @RequestScoped y  ViewScoped juntos. Y tambien que no le pongas un nombre al ManagedBean como así: ManagedBean(name = "cambiarEstadoPlazaAccBean")

Comment: En el managedBean le tengo puesto (name = "MercadoBean")  el problema que me hallo es en la función del obtener por código en el MercadoBean para que me permita modificar cualquier fila soy nuevo en esto de aplicaciones web saludos

Comment: lo que podrias hacer quitar RequestScoped porque tienes dos alcances en una misma pantalla eso puede crear conflicto

Comment: listo ya le elimine el RequestScoped gracias por la ayuda que me estas brindado

Comment: Probalo y me contas si no es eso va hacer un problema con los ajax que siempre da en primefaces

Comment: igual me sale los campos vacíos no estoy seguro de que la función del obtener en el MercadoBean este  bien hecha

Comment: ya revisaste el log que te esta mostrando

Comment: en esta parte yo veo q le estas enviano un parametro en la consulta y en el codigo el envias una lista con dos objetos esta correcto asi? List<Parametro> lst= new ArrayList<>(); lst.add(new Parametro(1,codigo)); ResultSet rst= con.ejecutaQuery(sql, lst);

Comment: la parte de la capa de funciones si esta bien realizada ya lo comprobé haciendo un test con el junit en eso del obtener en el MercadoBean dudo que este bien, si esta bien como tu lo dices estoy enviando un parámetro a la consulta  como la implementaría eso en el obtener del MercadoBean?

Comment: Solo envía la variable código pero puedes correrlo en modo debug

Comment: me podrías dar el ejemplo  de como lo haría en el obtener del mercadoBean?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falta para que la consulta funcione  NamedParameterStatement que hace que te funcione ya que es necesario para que funcionen los filtros.

```
public class FMercado {
public static Mercado obtener(int  codigo){
Mercado mercado=null;

Conexion con=new Conexion();
String query = "SELECT codigo, nombre, direccion FROM mercado_comprobantes.mercado where codigo=:codigo";

NamedParameterStatement p = new NamedParameterStatement(con, query);
p.setInteger("codigo", codigo);
ResultSet rst=p.executeQuery();

  try {
    while(rst.next()){
    mercado=new Mercado();
    mercado.setCodigo(rst.getInt("codigo"));
    mercado.setNombre(rst.getString("nombre"));
    mercado.setDireccion(rst.getString("direccion"));
}

    con.desconectar();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return mercado;
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda  ya me sale los campos llenos en la fila requerida

Comment: De nada espero q te haya servido